# How can I create my own resource type annotation like @StringRes?

Tags: java, android-studio, static-analysis, lint

Android provides [support annotations](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/support-annotations), and I'm particularly interested in the `@StringRes` family annotations used to mark integer parameters in a way that you are forced to pass valid resources instead of any random value.

Using Android Studio I looked at the implementation of `@StringRes` and copied it into a custom class of my own in my project:

```
package com.foo.bar.model.db;

import java.lang.annotation.Documented;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.FIELD;
import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.LOCAL_VARIABLE;
import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.METHOD;
import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.PARAMETER;
import static java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.CLASS;

/**
 * Denotes that an integer parameter, field or method return value is expected
 * to be an integer resource reference (e.g. {@link android.R.integer#config_shortAnimTime}).
 */
@Documented
@Retention(CLASS)
@Target({METHOD, PARAMETER, FIELD, LOCAL_VARIABLE})
public @interface IntPk {
}
```

With this new `@IntPk` annotation I want to tag the integer fields of the classes that map database integer foreign keys in the hope that I won't mix foreign keys integer values from different tables/classes (as such I would have then `FooPk`, `BarPk`, etc for each class). However, when I write code like this:

```
    @IntegerRes int androidValue;
    androidValue = 42;
    @IntPk int customValue;
    customValue = 42;
```

Android Studio only highlights the `androidValue` assignment as seen in this screenshot:

[image: annotation trolling level over 9000]

As such it is obvious that the validation is performed by *something else* other than the class defining the annotation. Where does this happen? And more importantly, how could I do the same checks for my custom `@IntPk` as the Android SDK does for `@StringRes` and store it in my project for other developers in the team to have the same level of extra type checking?

Comment: If your annotation isn't just a Marker annotation, having an annotation alone isn't enough... you also need an annotation processor, likely a subclass of [`javax.annotation.processing.AbstractProcessor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/annotation/processing/AbstractProcessor.html), but it can be any class that implements `javax.annotation.processing.Processor`.  Note: I know very little about writing annotation processors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Powerlord is correct that you need to write an annotation processor.  The annotation processor will analyze your source code and issue warnings about mismatches between annotations and code.  You could copy and modify whatever is built into Android Studio.

Another possibility is to build upon the [Checker Framework](http://checkerframework.org/), a tool designed to make it easier to write annotation processors.  Its [Fake Enumeration Checker](http://types.cs.washington.edu/checker-framework/current/checker-framework-manual.html#fenum-checker) or its [Subtyping Checker](http://types.cs.washington.edu/checker-framework/current/checker-framework-manual.html#subtyping-checker) may already do what you need, or you can write your own checker that enforces your rules.  Although this is a more expressive and flexible solution, the downside is that this is not integrated into Android Studio.